# Injecting non-mocks defined by a @Configuration class into a unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

Java 8, JUnit 4 and Spring Boot 2.3 here. I have a situation where I have a `@Component`-annotated Spring Boot class that gets `@Autowired` with all its dependencies (the beans are defined in a `@Configuration`-annotated config class):

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {

    @Bean
    public List<Fizz> fizzes() {
        Fizz fizz = new Fizz(/*complex logic here*/);
        return new Collections.singletonList(fizz);
    }

    @Bean
    public Buzz buzz() {
        return new Buzz(/*complex logic here*/);
    }
    
}

@Component
public class ThingDoerinator {

    @Autowired
    private Lizz<Fizz> fizzes;

    @Autowired
    private Buzz buzz;

    public String doStuff() {
        // uses fizz and buzz extensively inside here...
    }
    
}
```

I can easily write a unit test to inject all of these dependencies as mocks:

```
public class ThingDoerinatorTest extends AbstractBaseTest {

    @Mock
    private List<Fizz> fizzes;

    @Mock
    private Buzz buzz;

    @InjectMocks
    private ThingDoerinator thingDoerinator;

    @Test
    public void should_do_all_the_stuff() {

        // given
        // TODO: specify fizzes/buzz mock behavior here

        // when
        String theThing = thingDoerinator.doStuff();

        // then
        // TODO: make some assertions, verify mock behavior, etc.

    }
}
```

And 80% of the time that works for me. However I am now trying to write some unit tests that are more like *integration* tests, where instead of injected mocks, I want the beans to be instantiated like normal and get wired into the `ThingDoerinator` class like they would be in production:

```
public class ThingDoerinatorTest extends AbstractBaseTest {

    @Mock
    private List<Fizz> fizzes;

    @Mock
    private Buzz buzz;

    @InjectMocks
    private ThingDoerinator thingDoerinator;

    @Test
    public void should_do_all_the_stuff() {

        // given
        // how do I grab the same Fizz and Buzz beans
        // that are defined in SomeConfig?

        // when -- now instead of mocks, fizzes and buzz are actually being called
        String theThing = thingDoerinator.doStuff();

        // then
        // TODO: make some assertions, verify mock behavior, etc.

    }
}
```

**How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: You are using field injection, and this is considered a bad practice sometimes. You can create a getter/setter or pass the dependencies with a constructor. Then, in your integration likely tests, inject with constructor or setter the instantiated dependency.

Comment: Thanks @UrbanoJVR (+1) but correct me if I'm wrong, then I'd have to manually create the `Fizz` and `Buzz` objects inside my test class, and take care that I instantiate them the same way I do from inside `SomeConfig`, correct? I'm hoping for a solution that allows me to instantiate them from `SomeConfig`.

Comment: Does your config work in production code??

Comment: Yes it does @code_mechanic

Comment: You want to mock them in integration test like UT or want to autowired like in production code? If, autowired then it should should work without you writing the mock/inject mock code.

Comment: I want `SomeConfig` to inject them into `ThingDoerinatorTest` or at least into a `ThingDoerinator` instance that I can use inside of `ThingDoerinatorTest`. So no mocking whatsoever.

Comment: As I said, if you are writing IT test, then you would most probably run the whole application context similar to the production server and then your config class which is already there would be loaded and you will have those beans, but if you want to tweak the bean creation logic for test, then go for `@TestConfiguration` to run for the test only.

Comment: OK thanks @code_mechanic (+1) -- if you can provide even a pseudo-code example that shows how I could do all this from inside a unit test I'd be very interested in taking a look at it! Thanks again!

Comment: You seems to be confused about integration test and unit test, if you are going to be using `@SpringBootTest` for your test class, it will load your existing config and your service class will have those objects, so I am not sure what you are not getting here?

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm confused about unit vs integration tests, I think you're just not reading my question and comments completely, and are making assumptions about my understanding, which is crystal clear. Integration tests don't use mocks, unit tests can use mocks.

Comment: I think Akif's answer below gets me 95% of the way to want I want, however, if you actually look at the code above you will see that `ThingDoerinator` needs to be `@Autowired`-injected with a **List** (`List<Fizz>`). The concern then is that if I specify the generic `@SpringBootTest(classes = { List.class, ... })` then it may inject other lists from the application context, not the `List<Fizz>` that I want. If you, Akif or anyone else can help get me past this particular hurdle, I think I have exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SpringBootTest.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Fizz.class, Buzz.class, ThingDoerinator.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ThingDoerinatorTest {
    @Autowired
    private Fizz fizz;

    @Autowired
    private Buzz buzz;

    @Autowired
    private ThingDoerinator thingDoerinator;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks @Akif (+1)! -- will this create `Fizz` and `Buzz` exactly as they are defined in `SomeConfig`? Also, why is `ThingDoerinator` a spy?

Comment: sorry ThingDoerinator is also spring managed bean and can be autowired, yes spring will create and inject these 3 beans in your test

Comment: OK scary question. What if `Fizz` is actually a `List<Fizz>`? And what if `Buzz` is really `List<Buzz>`? How do I specify those two different list types inside the `@SpringBootTest` annotation?!

Comment: You can use Autowired List<Fizz> fizzList, and you can create multiple beans with Primary and Qualifier annotations.

Comment: Apologies @Akif (+1) - I edited my original question to show what I mean, its an actual `List<Fizz>` that `SomeConfig` creates (using complex logic) and injects into my `ThingDoerinator`. Obviously I can't use `@SpringBootTest(classes = {List.class, Buzz.class, ThingDoerinator.class})` because then any list of _anything_ could be used. Any chance you could update your code example to show how I would inject the list of fizzes into the test? Thanks again so much for all your help with this!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mock anything, just inject your class in your test and your configuration will provide the beans to your `ThingDoerinator` class and your test case will work as if you are calling the `ThingDoerinator. doStuff()` method from some controller or other service.

**TL;DR**

I think, you are confused with tests running whole spring context and unit test which just test the function/logic we wrote without running whole context. Unit tests are written to test the piece of function, if that function would behave as expected with given set of inputs.

Ideal unit test is that which doesn't require a mock, we just pass the input and it produces the output (pure function) but often in real application this is not the case, we may find ourselves in situation when we interact with some other object in our application. As we are not about to test that object interaction but concerned about our function, we mock that object behaviours.

It seems, you have no issue with unit test, so you could mock your `List` of bean in your test class `ThingDoerinator` and inject them in your test case and your test case worked fine.

Now, you want to do the same thing with `@SpringBootTest`, so I am taking a hypothetical example to demonstrate that you don't need to mock object now, as spring context will have them, when `@springBootTest` will load whole context to run your single test case.

Let's say I have a service `FizzService` and it has one method `getFizzes()`

```
@Service
public class FizzService {
    private final List<Fizz> fizzes;

    public FizzService(List<Fizz> fizzes) {
        this.fizzes = fizzes;
    }

    public List<Fizz> getFizzes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(fizzes);
    }
}
```

> Using constructor injection here<sup>1</sup>

Now, my `List<Fizzes` would be created through a configuration (similar to your case) and been told to spring context to inject them as required.

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
public class FizzConfig {

    @Bean
    public List<Fizz> allFizzes() {
        return asList(Fizz.of("Batman"), Fizz.of("Aquaman"), Fizz.of("Wonder Woman"));
    }
}
```

> Ignore the @Profile annotation for now<sup>2</sup>

Now I would have spring boot test to check that if this service will give same list of `fizzes` which I provided to the context, when it will run in production

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
class FizzServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private FizzService service;

    @Test
    void shouldGiveAllTheFizzesInContext() {
        List<Fizz> fizzes = service.getFizzes();

        assertThat(fizzes).isNotNull().isNotEmpty().hasSize(3);
        assertThat(fizzes).extracting("name")
                          .contains("Wonder Woman", "Aquaman");
    }

}
```

Now, when I ran the test, I saw it works, so how did it work, let's understand this. So when I run the test with `@SpringBootTest` annotation, it will run similar like it runs in production with embedded server.

So, my config class which I created earlier, will be scanned and then beans created there would be loaded into the context, also my service class annotated with `@Service` annotation, so that would be loaded as well and spring will identify that it needs `List<Fizz>` and then it will look into it's context that if it has that bean so it will find and inject it, because we are supplying it from our config class.

In my test, I am auto wiring the service class, so spring will inject the `FizzService` object it has and it would have my `List<Fizz>` as well (explained in previous para).

So, you don't have to do anything, if you have your config defined and those are being loaded and working in production, those should work in your spring boot test the same way unless you have some custom setup than default spring boot application.

Now, let's look at a case, when you may want to have different `List<Fizz>` in your test, in that case you will have to exclude the production config and include some test config.

In my example to do that I would create another `FizzConfig` in my test folder and annotate it with `@TestConfiguration`

```
@TestConfiguration
public class FizzConfig {
    @Bean
    public List<Fizz> allFizzes() {
        return asList(Fizz.of("Flash"), Fizz.of("Mera"), Fizz.of("Superman"));
    }
}
```

And I would change my test a little

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Import(FizzConfig.class)
class FizzServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private FizzService service;

    @Test
    void shouldGiveAllTheFizzesInContext() {
        List<Fizz> fizzes = service.getFizzes();
        assertThat(fizzes).extracting("name")
                          .contains("Flash", "Superman");
    }

}
```

Using different profile for tests, hence @ActiveProfile annotation, otherwise the default profile set is `dev` which will load the production `FizzConfig` class as it would scan all the packages ( <sup>2</sup>Remember the `@Profile` annotation above, this will make sure that earlier config only runs in production/dev env ). Here is my application.yml to make it work.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
---
spring:
  profiles: test
```

Also, notice that I am importing my `FizzConfiguration` with `@Import` annotation here, you can also do same thing with `@SpringBootTest(classes = FizzConfig.class)`.

So, you can see test case has different values than in production code.

**Edit**

As commented out, since you don't want test to connect to database in this test, you would have to disable auto configuration for spring data JPA, which spring boot by default does that.

<sup>3</sup>You can create a another configuration class like

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public TestDataSourceConfiguration {}
```

And then include that with your `@SpringBootTest`, this will disable default database setup and then you would be left with last piece of puzzle which is any repository interaction you might be having in your class.

Because now, you don't have auto configuration in your test case, those repository are just interfaces, which you can easily mock inside your test class

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Import(FizzConfig.class, TestDataSourceConfiguration.class)
class FizzServiceTest {
    @MockBean
    SomeRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private FizzService service;

    @Test
    void shouldGiveAllTheFizzesInContext() {
        // Use Mockito to mock behaviour of repository
        Mockito.when(repository.findById(any(), any()).thenReturn(Optional.of(new SomeObject));
 
        List<Fizz> fizzes = service.getFizzes();
        assertThat(fizzes).extracting("name")
                          .contains("Flash", "Superman");
    }

}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Constructor injection is advisable instead of `@Autowired` in production code, if your dependencies are really required for that class to work, so please avoid it if possible.

---

<sup>3</sup>Please note that you create such configuration only in test package or mark with some profile, do not create it in your production packages, otherwise it will disable database for your running code.

Comment: Thanks @code_mechanic (+1), I tried your method, and it looks like it runs the _entire_ application context, and is even trying to connect to a local database (in my `application.yml` I do specify configurations for a connection to a MySQL DB). Is there any way to isolate this so that _only_ the beans specified in `FizzConfig` are loaded? Because, for this test case, those are the only beans I need/want Spring to load for me. Thanks again for the help here!

Comment: You can exclude database auto configuration from `@SpringBootTest` and mock the repository bean if any in your code using `@MockBean`

Comment: Ahh ok, maybe something like this then: `@SpringBootTest(exclude={CrudRepository.class})` maybe?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the only thing you have to do, because you have to disable the auto configuration for database which spring boot does by default if you have jpa on path

Comment: Updated my answer to show what may be required to achieve that.